# Issue handling custom makefile in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

Basically I'm trying to use a project, that already has a makefile, in eclipse.

I've created a new project and pasted in the source files in the /src directory. 
I've also pasted the makefile named Makefile in the /src directory as well.
Here are the contents of Makefile:

```
all: bosh

OBJS = parser.o print.o
LIBS= -lreadline -ltermcap
CC = gcc

bosh: bosh.o ${OBJS}
    ${CC} -o $@ bosh.o ${OBJS} ${LIBS}

clean:
    rm -rf *o bosh
```

However how do I get Eclipse to use my makefile instead of creating one?

I suppose I need to change the Build command and the Build directory in my project properties but what do I need to input?

Answer (score 0):

Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> uncheck "Generate Makefiles Automatically."

For your own makefile, you can open the View called "Make Target"

Window -> Show View -> Make Target